Will my code use the FPU of the embedded system?
Assume I have an embedded system with a processor that has a FPU on it (just to be clear, I'm not talking about a specific micro-controller, I'm trying to understang the subject in a broad manner).
I wanted to create a program to evaluate the taylor series of e^x for a given x,
and only use integer and fixed point operations (without the usage of the FPU).
as a part of implementing Horner's Rule, I find myself multiplying a float variable with an integer and taking the result into an integer variable (the round down part).
the evaluation is correct, but, how can I know if the program is going to call on the FPU to perform the multiplication ?
the specific line that I am worried about:
res += x*int_polynomial[i]; -> where x is a float variable and res,int_polynomial are integers (long and regualr)
the complete code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N          7 // 6rd order polynomial
#define Q          15
#define E_CONST    2.718281828459045

int factor_ = 1<<Q;
float taylor_coeffs[] = {1.000000,1.000000, 0.500000, 0.166667,0.041667, 0.008333, 0.001389};
int int_polynomial[N] = {0};

void get_int_coeffs()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<N; i++)
    {
        int_polynomial[i] = taylor_coeffs[i]*factor_;
    }
}
double horners_rule(float x)
{
    long long res;
    double res_;
    int i;
    for(i=0,res=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        res += x*int_polynomial[i];
    }
    return res_ = (float)res/factor_;
    //OR:
    // res_ = res; // insert res value into a double type variable
    // return res_ /= factor_; // divide and return
}
float error_(double y, double y_hat)
{
    return sqrt(pow(y-y_hat,2));
}
int main()
{
    double y_hat;
    float eval_error;
    get_int_coeffs();
    y_hat = horners_rule(1);
    eval_error = error_(E_CONST,y_hat);

    printf("polynomial evaluated to y_hat = %lf\n",y_hat);
    printf("error = %f\n",eval_error);
}



I hope I am making myself clear and you guys can help me understand better :)
I am trying to evaluate the result of a taylor expansion of a given function, using unteger operations and fixed point operations only (without using a FPU)

Which system do you use? On which CPU is it based? Which C compiler do you use?

Look at what instructions are used in the disassembly view or the .lst file.

It depends on compiler and MCU. You are using double precision floating point. Does your FPU support that or just single precision (as is common with Cortex M)? In fact you are mixing single and double precision in an unholy mess which is wrong programming practice on 100% of all computers no matter FPU.

On Cortex-M4F for example, you can disable the FPU, but your code will then use software floating-point, not integer or fixed point math.  So it still may not achieve your aim, which to be honest is entirely unclear.  If you don't want to use floating point, do not use float or double or the standard math library.

I agree with @Clifford. You are using floats and doubles all over the place. In order to transfer the code to fixed point operations use see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic .

... and also https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/optimizing-applications-with-fixed-point-arithmetic.html, if there were only one reason to use C++ on embedded systems, this is it for me.  You can largely replace float or double with fixed in existing code and it will normally work. Or you can use it in a more OO manner. There a few missing bits such as atan2 and pow as well as string conversions, but I have added these myself over time.


Will my code use the FPU of the embedded system?

The short answer is yes :)

The longer answer:

how can I know if the program is going to call on the FPU to perform the multiplication ?

To prove it to yourself, you need to compile the code for the system you're working on, then look at the disassembly of the binary. That's the only way to know for sure the compiler is generating floating point operations.
For example, if you take this snippet that represents the section of your code in question and put it into godbolt.org with ARM GCC 11.2.1 and flags  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c17 -mfloat-abi=hard (this is an example compiler configuration, its most important that you're using a compiler and flags that generate code for a target MCU with a FPU on board)
int int_polynomial[7];
double horners_rule(float x)
{
    long long res;
    double res_;
    int i;
    for(i=0,res=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        res += x*int_polynomial[i];
    }
}

Then you can see the generated FPU instructions like: vcvt.f32.s32    s14, s15. I like godbolt because you can hover over the assembly instructions for a reminder of what each does.
To know if code will use FPU before compiling it you should learn the "Usual arithmetic conversions" rules for C. Those rules will tell you that in an expression like x * int_polynomial[i] where x is float and int_polynomial[i] is int, the value of int_polynomial[i] will be "implicitly converted" to a float and the expression will be evaluated as a floating point multiplication.
Pretty much any code that uses float or double type variables will use the FPU.

The compiler will not necessarily generate FPU instructions at all because the M4 uses a single precision FPU but double was used. So it might as well load a bloated software floating point lib all over the place. Step 1 here is for the OP to de-sloppify their code. If they use Cortext M4 then sticking to float all over would be the correct way to write programs.

Thank you very much for your kind answer!


Is there a way to carry an operation on a floating point number without getting the FPU involved ? what will happend on a micro-controller who does not have a FPU if I wanted to declare a float variable and perform addition \ multiplication on it ?


where can I learn more about understanding the assembly code that my program will be converted to ?


is there a common known way to implement horner's rule with integers only ? (something like a modified way of using Q representations?)


thank you again sir !

"Is there a way to carry an operation on a floating point number without getting the FPU involved ?" - yes, but it is almost always a bad choice. Instead of generating FPU instructions, the compiler will instead link to a builtin library function to perform the floating point operation; that single operation can take hundreds or thousands of CPU cycles, it is hard to determine. Here is the implementation of one https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/blob/master/lib/libutils/isoc/arch/arm/arm32_aeabi_softfloat.c#L150.  I am assuming you are doing this for performance reasons.

I highly recommend playing around on https://godbolt.org/ for learning what assembly gets generated. Otherwise invest the time to learn GNU binutils very well and use developer.arm.com for reference on each assembly instruction.

@GandhiGandhi Thank you very much!

Related analysis
Sub-optimal coefficients
Instead of weakly rounded manual values, use more precise computed values.
  float taylor_coeffs[] = {1.000000,1.000000, 0.500000, 0.166667,0.041667, 0.008333, 0.001389};
  float taylor_coeffs2[] = {1.000000,1.000000, 0.500000, 1/6.0,1/24.0, 1/120.0, 1/720.0};

  size_t n = sizeof taylor_coeffs / sizeof taylor_coeffs[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%zu %-15a %-15a %c\n", i, taylor_coeffs[i], taylor_coeffs2[i],
        taylor_coeffs[i] == taylor_coeffs2[i] ? ' ' : '*');
  }

Output
0 0x1p+0          0x1p+0           
1 0x1p+0          0x1p+0           
2 0x1p-1          0x1p-1           
3 0x1.555582p-3   0x1.555556p-3   *
4 0x1.555608p-5   0x1.555556p-5   *
5 0x1.110e46p-7   0x1.111112p-7   *
6 0x1.6c1e36p-10  0x1.6c16c2p-10  *

A step toward only use integer and fixed point operations
Rather than 1.000000,1.000000, 0.500000, 0.166667,0.041667, 0.008333, 0.001389, note that ex coefficients are all reciprocals of integer values.
Instead of floating point multiplication of an approximate coefficient, re-code to use integer math of an exact coefficient.
const int inverse_taylor_coeffs[] = {
    1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720};

// taylor_coeffs[i]*factor_
factor_ / inverse_taylor_coeffs[i]



Assume I have an embedded system with a processor that has a FPU on it

"FPU" could mean single precision, as seen with ARM Cortex M4, or double precision, as seen with x86 and other high end cores.


I wanted to create a program to evaluate the taylor series of e^x for a given x, and only use integer and fixed point operations (without the usage of the FPU).

So use int32_t/int64_t only and not floating point. Because if you use floating point types you'll get floating point inaccuracy needlessly, regardless of if it uses the FPU or a software floating point lib. You will get floating point and not fixed point when you type float (hence the name) and this should not be surprising.


how can I know if the program is going to call on the FPU to perform the multiplication ?

It depends on what your MCU can handle and what the compiler chose to do with the code. In C code, float corresponds to single precision and double to double precision (hence the name, unsurprisingly).
Now if you have a FPU which only supports single precision (like on Cortex M4), the compiler will be forced to ignore that fancy FPU and instead load a bloated, slow software floating point lib into your MCU, because it noticed that you are using double all over the place and the compiler is not allowed to optimize out your specified precision.
What you can know for sure is that the calculation is not carried out in fixed point.


the specific line that I am worried about: res += x*int_polynomial[i];

The operands of * is float and int in that case. Implicit type conversion according to "the usual arithmetic conversion" will first force the int operand to become a float and then the multiplication is carried out as float. Now if you have a single precision FPU and the compiler does its job correctly, it should indeed generate a floating point instruction for the multiplication.
However, you then store the result in a double meaning that the compiler will have to generate a lot of excessive bloat code to deal with that. Because you told it to.
It is never correct to mix float and double inside the same function no matter the target. Similarly, we need to know the basics: literals of type 1.0f have type float and literals of type 1.0 have type double. sqrtf uses float, sqrt uses double. And so on. So code like
float taylor_coeffs[] = {1.000000 ....

is definitely incorrect. Most of the time it won't matter, but if you managed to type something which couldn't get exactly represented then you've introduced an inaccuracy bug.

Best practices:

Never mix different floating point types in the same expression.
Never mix floating point an integer types in the same expression, without explicit casts.
Be aware that going from floating point to unsigned integer is sometimes not well-defined behavior.
Old C90 had interesting language defects in terms of poorly-defined int negative division rounding direction, so avoid using very old C compilers.
Never use the types int/long etc in (embedded systems) programming. Always use the stdint.h types.


First of all, thank you for your informative response. I am a DSP engineer, used to work in an algorithm team and now I'm getting into (and fairly new at) the field of "low level" computing. Your answer is deep and it will take me a couple of days to dive into everything.
One thing that I didn't fully grasp at first sight:
you said that a FPU could be built for single precision or double precision calculations.
Suppose I have a FPU that is designed to carry single precision operations, what will happend with a variable of double precision ? Where can I learn more about this subject ?

@RotemCalisir As mentioned in the answer, the compiler isn't allowed to round down variables and reduce precision. So if you have told it to use double but the FPU can't handle that, you force the compiler to load a bloated software floating point lib and handle everything in software instead, which is slow and memory consuming.

Note that Cortex-M4F has a single precision FPU M7F is double precision.

@Clifford Good point! I've actually never used a M7 personally. I'll edit the answer.

@Lundin - "you force the compiler to load a bloated software floating point lib and handle everything in software instead" - > can you elaborate ? what is going to happen on the software level ?

@RotemCalisir Example with godawful AVR, an 8 bitter without FPU: https://godbolt.org/z/aE7zd7of7. Simple addition at a glance resulted in 57(!) instructions, but then there's also rcall __addsf3 which is a call to an internal function provided with the compiler libs and could contain some hundreds of extra instructions for all we know. In this example, the floating point numbers are causing a complete slaughter of everything that's execution speed and program size and obviously we should never have picked this MCU to begin with if we actually needed floating point math.

A Cortex M4 won't perform that poorly but it would still have to do a library function call to resolve double arithmetic.

@Lundin Thank you very much!

The short answer is that it will call conversion function on all Cortex-M targets. Only big beast like Cortex A will handle it without them :)
